# GC Pauses the Full Application Activity

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection

I am building a web crawler in .Net which executes approx 500 httpwebrequests at a time.
Everything runs fine but the problem arise at some points; Looks like garbage collection thread takes over the whole application pause for a few seconds. Is there anyway that reduce the delay generated by GC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guidance on how to avoid GC problems in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)

> To get the best out of the allocator
>   you should consider practices such as
>   the following:
>
> - Allocate all of the memory (or as much as possible) to be used with a
>     given data structure at the same time.
> - Remove temporary allocations that can be avoided with little
>     penalty in complexity.
> - Minimize the number of times object pointers get written,
>     especially those writes made to older
>     objects.
> - Reduce the density of pointers in your data structures.
> - Make limited use of finalizers, and then only on "leaf" objects, as
>     much as possible. Break objects if
>     necessary to help with this.
>
> A regular practice of reviewing your
>   key data structures and conducting
>   memory usage profiles with tools like
>   Allocation Profiler will go a long way
>   to keeping your memory usage effective
>   and having the garbage collector
>   working its best for you.

You can [request a GC](http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3a_How_can_I_force_garbage_collection%3F) at some more convenient time which may reduce the pauses later

Also look at the related StackOverflow questions to the right - there are some relevant ones there ----->